# parsing XML Data using c#

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xmlreader

I have been struggling with the XMLReaderClass in c# for some time now and just can't seem to get the concept. Basically I want to loop through the XML File and if the category in the xml doc is the same as the category I have passed it in, I want to add its name to a List.

here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- Do not modify this xml file. -->
<Products>
    <product category="Food"  name="Baking potatoes" />
    <product category="Food" name="Chicken fillet" />
    <product category="Food" name="Chocolate gateau" />
    <product category="Food" name="Madras curry sauce" />
    <product category="Food" name="Organic carrots" />
    <product category="Food" name="Semi-skimmed milk" />
    <product category="Home" name="Washing powder" />
    <product category="Home" name="Rubber gloves" />
    <product category="Home" name="Spray wax" />
    <product category="Home" name="Dish soap" />
    <product category="Pet" name="Cat food" />
    <product category="Pet" name="Dog food" />
    <product category="Pet" name="Collar" />
    <product category="Pet" name="Leash" />
</Products>
```

and here is my code I have started to work on but didn't get very far :(

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<string> GetProductsByCategory(string category)
    {
        List<string> returnList = new List<string>();

        using (XmlReader productsReader = GetProductsReader())
        {


            productsReader.MoveToContent();
            while (productsReader.Read())

                if(productsReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                if (productsReader)
                {
                    if productsReader
                }
            }

        }

        return new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(returnList);
    }
```

Comment: This is a perfect task for LINQ. Are you intentionally trying not to use that?

Comment: Why do you want to use XmlReader instead of the more friendly XDocument or XmlDocument classes?

Comment: long story short, I have to use the XMLReader

Comment: What is the long story, are you stuck with .NET 2.0?  You can use an XMLReader to load the data into an XDocument like @Jeff Mercado suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `XmlReader` here will just be a pain to use.  Use LINQ to XML here using that API instead, it will make your life easier.

```
public static ReadOnlyCollection<string> GetProductsByCategory(string category)
{
    using (var reader = GetProductsReader())
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
        var results = doc.Element("Products")
            .Elements("product")
            .Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("category") == category)
            .Select(e => (string)e.Attribute("name"))
            .ToList();
        return new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(results);
    }
}
```

If for whatever reason you still wish to use the `XmlReader`, you could read it like this:

```
public static ReadOnlyCollection<string> GetProductsByCategory(string category)
{
    var results = new List<string>();
    var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
    {
        IgnoreWhitespace = true,
        IgnoreComments = true,
    };
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(GetProductsReader(), settings))
    {
        reader.MoveToContent();
        reader.ReadStartElement("Products");
        do
        {
            if (reader.IsStartElement("product"))
            {
                if (reader.MoveToFirstAttribute())
                {
                    string currentCategory = null;
                    string currentName = null;
                    do
                    {
                        switch (reader.Name)
                        {
                        case "category":
                            currentCategory = reader.ReadContentAsString();
                            break;
                        case "name":
                            currentName = reader.ReadContentAsString();
                            break;
                        }
                    } while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute());
                    if (currentCategory == category && currentName != null)
                        results.Add(currentName);
                }
            }
        } while (reader.ReadToNextSibling("product"));
    }
    return new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(results);
}
```

Comment: long story short, I have to use the XMLReader

Comment: Fortunately, you can load the contents of the reader here as I have shown so it's not a problem.  You just shouldn't be using the `XmlReader` yourself to process it, _that's_ the painful part.

Answer (score 1):

For extremely large XML files, using `XmlReader` to scan through the document can be more efficient than using `XmlDocument` or `XDocument`, which require that the entire file be loaded into memory. Access the `XmlReader.LocalName` property to determine the kind of element the reader is positioned on, and call the `XmlReader.GetAttribute()` method to get the value of an attribute.

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<string> GetProductsByCategory(string category)
{
    List<string> products = new List<string>();

    using (XmlReader productsReader = GetProductsReader())
    {
        productsReader.MoveToContent();

        while (productsReader.Read())
        {
            if (productsReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element &&
                productsReader.LocalName == "product" &&
                productsReader.GetAttribute("category") == category)
            {
                products.Add(productsReader.GetAttribute("name"));
            }
        }
    }

    return new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(products);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use LINQ to XMl (XDocument) instead of the old reader.  This will get you started (assuming your xml is in a file in your c:\temp directory):

```
  var doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\testxml.xml");
  foreach(var element in doc.Elements("Products").Elements())
  {
    Console.WriteLine(element.Attribute("category"));
  }
```

Comment: long story short, I have to use the XMLReader

Comment: @shenn Bummer -- Michael Liu's implementation looks pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Linq to XML, here is an example looking for a specific attribute

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387041.aspx

Comment: long story short, I have to use the XMLReader