# How Do I Use the Quandl API?

Tags: c#, quandl

I'm using C# and I want to know how to use the Quandl API to get data via xml, like a stock price. I've never used an API before so I'm really lost. I was looking at their quick start guide, but I don't understand how something like "https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/FB.xml" gets you anything. How do I make the API work? Can I even do it with C#?

Comment: perhaps you could have done a google search for example [C# and Quandl API examples](https://www.quandl.com/blog/getting-started-with-the-quandl-api) this came up as one of the first choices

Comment: Do you know anything about parsing?

Comment: I know nothing about parsing. @JBKing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975961/parsing-xml-data-using-c-sharp could be useful in how to use the XML classes of C# to read the data so that it could be useful for you.

Comment: But how do I get the data in the 1st place? @JBKing

Comment: Make an account. Understand which data sources may charge you and be prepared for that.

Comment: https://www.quandl.com/docs/api#introduction would be my suggested starting point for understanding the API configuration.

Comment: But how do I code it? Like if I wanted to store a stock price into a variable or something. I've been looking at their API documentation and I'm not getting anywhere. @JBKing

Comment: How are you wanting this to work: Console Application, Windows Application, Mobile Application, Web Application or something else? I did write some code once to get data from Quandl on a web application a year ago now though first you need to have a key, know what data set you want to use and then built the URL to get that data using your key so Quandl knows who is accessing which dataset. Do you at least understand that much?

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, I signed up and have a key and I get that you have to pick a data set. I want to make a console app that prints a stock price. I have no clue on how to implement that functionality though. @JBKing

Comment: Ever look at how to write a "Hello World" console app? That does tend to be the first program written for developers in a new language or platform.

Answer (score 1):

With javascript you'd rather use the json format of your chosen dataset: https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/FB.json, instead of https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/FB.xml.
Then write a classical XMLHttpRequest:

```
var url = "https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/FB.json";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.onload = function() {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText).dataset.data;
    // {}.dataset.data is the data matrix in Quandl
    // then process your own way
}
xhr.send();
```